# jsoup: not selecting all rows in a table

Tags: select, jsoup

I have a web page containing a table, where each row has either class vc_row_odd or vc_row_even, like this. The table has about 3000 rows, but using jsoup I am retrieving only about half of them. 
I have looked at the source page, and the rows seem consistently structured. Why is jsoup selector not finding all rows I wonder ?

Here below is my jsoup code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).header("Authorization", 
              "Basic " + base64login).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
Elements trs = doc.select("tr[class~=vc_row_(odd|even)]");
logger.debug("Size trs " + trs.size());


<tr class="vc_row_odd">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="vc_row_even">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution with setting maxSizeLimit to zero
http://jmchung.github.io/blog/2013/10/25/how-to-solve-jsoup-does-not-get-complete-html-document/

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself, the link in the existing self-answer is dead, but according to the latest archived version[1], the option is called maxBodySize[2], not maxSizeLimit. The default is 1MB, setting it to zero turns the limit off.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(DATA_URL).maxBodySize(0).get();
```

Sources:

- [1] https://web.archive.org/web/20180209022028/http://jmchung.github.io/blog/2013/10/25/how-to-solve-jsoup-does-not-get-complete-html-document/
- [2] https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#maxBodySize-int-